# Winform: Panel with scroll needs to have their width/height defined?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've a winform usercontrol, that has a Panel, which is containing some TableLayout(which have also some other user controls).

All my components have a `Dock=Fill` and `Autosize=True` properties.

Currently, when I resize the windows, I don't have any scrollbar, the overflow is just no show.

I found that if I set the AutoScrollMinSize of my panel to something, I'm having those scrollbar appearing when I reach the set size.

My problem is that I add/remove elements on runtime, and I've also some things that I display or not depending the configuration. So for me it's very hard to hardcode here a value, either I've scrollbar too soon, or too late.

I'm sure there should be a way to configure my userControl, without having to calculate myself the size, to have the component displaying scrollbar, when the children's content cannot be displayed, do you know how?

Thank you!

Comment: Calculating the size is the way to do it, this is not difficult.  In general avoid putting a lot of time into making UI usable in a mode that the user will never use because it becomes too cumbersome.  Make sure it is usable in a 1024x768 window size without scrollbars.  A simple way to make it still operable when it is smaller is to make the form scrollable.  Set its AutoScroll property to True and AutoScrollMinSize large enough to display the TLP.

Comment: It's not what I'm asking. I've constraint from the customer that are related to his business. E.g., the width can be 1000 or 1300 parameters if they are admin, they wanted that way

Comment: Yeah, I'll buy that.  It is 1024 and 1366, the commonly available screen widths.  Always nice to have a customer that knows exactly what he wants.  You better get on it and redesign your layout so they fit these screen sizes without a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the AutoScrollMinSize value on the panel resize event or the form's resize event. That way, it won't be a fixed value and there will be a scrollbar available if the panel's child controls go beyond the panel edges -

```
private void panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
}
```